# Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't understand why, but seems that the code doesn't find the model created.

This is my **index.php** file structure:

```
<?php 
require_once("class/settings.php"); 
    $this->load->model('impostazioni_model');
    $this->impostazioni_model->load_colours();
?>
```

and this is the model `impostazioni`, `settings.php` class

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Esecuzione diretta dello script non consentita.'); 

require_once("class/config.php"); 


class Impostazioni_Model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function __construct() 
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function load_colours()
   {
       echo "example";
   }
}
?>
```

the `config.php` contains the details of the connection, is simple a definition of the connection paramters like host, user, password and database. 
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Why are you including your own `config.php`?  Why not just use CodeIgniter's `config/database.php`?  Also try this: `$this->load->model('Impostazioni_model');`, I think the capitalization makes a difference.  You should also change your class to `Impostazioni_model` (and make sure it's saved as `impostazioni_model.php`).

Comment: 'Cause I'm using easyappointments library and actually I don't want use the connection file of the library, anyway, same error returned.

Comment: index.php ? You mean, your controller right ? Also check your filenames, they must be ucfirst

Comment: Okay now in the line that call the function 'load_colours()' I get this error: Message: Undefined property: CI_Loade

why?

Comment: we need to know what version of codeigniter you are using - the model file names being upper case is for codeigniter 3 -- not codeigniter 2.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, `Impostazioni_Model` should be `Impostazioni_model`

> **Model** :
>
> 1. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the
>    rest of the name lowercase.
> 2. The file name must match the class name.